# Replacement of a word within a string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to replace a word within a sentence with another word.
For ex. if str1="strong" and str2="weak", then the 1st string in str should get changed      to "If the core is weak, you can't go wrong".
I am getting segmentation fault(core dumped) error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void func(char *str,char *str1,char *str2,int l1,int l2)
{
 int i,m,j,c;

 for(i=0;*(str+i)!='\0';i++)
    {
      if(*(str+i)==*str1)
       {
        for(m=i,j=0;j<l1;m++,j++)       /*checking the equality of the two words*/
         {
          if(*(str+m)!=*(str1+j))
            break;
          else
           c=1;
         }
        if(c==1)
        { 
          for(j=i;*(str+j)!='\0';j++)
             *(str+j+l2-l1)=*(str+j);
          for(m=0,j=i;(*(str2+m)!='\0');j++,m++)
            *(str+j)=*(str2+m);
        }
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
  char *str[]={
              "If the core is strong, you can't go wrong",
              "Canada's wonder of the world",
              "Processing a sorted array",
              "Was that a joke?", 
              "I wanna be a millionaire",
              "Your post is not properly formatted"
             };

 int i,l1,l2,k,j;
 char str1[10],str2[10];
 l1=strlen(str1);
 l2=strlen(str2);
 printf("Enter string 1 : ");
 scanf("%s",str1);
 printf("\nEnter string 2 : ");
 scanf("%s",str2);

 for(k=0;k<=5;k++)
  func(str[k],str1,str2,l1,l2);    

 for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;*(str[i]+j)!='0';j++)
      printf("%c",*(str[i]+j));
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: For start, you are calculating `l1` and `l2` before reading string itself..Also use debugger and see where you get segmentation fault

Comment: first, You have no idea how many times you try to change a string literal: constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 char *str[]={
              "If the core is strong, you can't go wrong",
              "Canada's wonder of the world",
              "Processing a sorted array",
              "Was that a joke?", 
              "I wanna be a millionaire",
              "Your post is not properly formatted"
             };
```

This creates a array of character pointers and each pointer points to a string literal and if you modify a string literal it will result in segmentation fault since it is in read-only memory. this is the reason that you are getting segmentation fault.
Do check your logical errors too in your code.

Comment: ok...so I need to store the edited strings at a different place...am I right?

Comment: @ncoder you can store the string in array that can be modified like str[][size] or you can do the changes on a different string that has editable memory. you can use dynamic memory allocation or a statically allocated character array

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unfortunately wrong on many levels. Others have already pointed out the string literal issue, and the issue with `strlen()` before `scanf()` in `main()`, but there is more wrong:
1. You try to edit the string in-place. What happens if you replace a sub-string with a longer string? You try to move the string forward. But *that* means you write past the end of the memory allocated to the string. This is undefined behaviour and may crash.
2. In `func()`:

```
[snip]
if(c==1)
    { 
      for(j=i;*(str+j)!='\0';j++)
         *(str+j+l2-l1)=*(str+j);
      for(m=0,j=i;(*(str2+m)!='\0');j++,m++)
        *(str+j)=*(str2+m);
    }
```

You iterate until the *source string* is null-terminated, but **you don't copy the null-terminator!** Later on, you try to `printf()` the string (character by character, for some unfathomable reason, also not checking for a null-terminator but for an ASCII `'0'`...), which will then crash due to the lack of null-termination.
To solve your issues, you can do the following:
1. Walk through the string using `strstr()` to find the sub-string to replace. Count the number of occurrences of the sub-string.
2. Use `strlen()` in `func()` to determine the length of the sub-string and the replacement. Multiply the difference by the number of occurrences of the sub-string to find how much longer or shorter your new string will be. Add the difference to `strlen()` of the original string to find out how much memory to allocate (Remember to allocate an extra byte for null-termination).
3. Allocate the needed memory with `malloc()`.
4. Use a combination of `strcpy()/strncpy()/memmove()/strstr()/whatever standard library functions you need` to assemble your new string.

Comment: strlen() before scanf() and checking for an ASCII '0' were not intentional...my bad..I typed it wrong.

Comment: and I dont want to use too many library functions as I am trying to build my basics.

Comment: @ncoder: That's not a good reason to write broken code. If you don't want to rely on the stdlib, write your own replacement functions. Don't cram everything into one special-case function.